# Axios does not send the form data to the laravel controller

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3

I've a Laravel project with Vue 3 front end and I'm using a Box Spout package to upload a xlsx file to my MySQL
At my local machine everything works perfectly! but when I upload my project to a live server axios  seems not triggering my controller at all!

HERE IS MY CONTROLER CODE :

```
    function importData(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
        ]);
        $the_file = $request->file('file');
        try{

            ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

            $the_file = $request->file('file');

            $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
            $reader ->open($the_file);

               $data = array();
            foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
                foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                    // do stuff with the row
                    $cells = $row->getCells();
                             $data[] = [
                    'pr_number' =>$cells[0],
                    'state' =>0,
                    'user_id' =>auth()->id(),
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    
                ];
                }
            }

            $reader->close();
            $limit = 65000; // Mysql placeholder limit ...

            // foreach (array_chunk($data,1000) as $t)
            // {
            //      DB::table('table_name')->insert($t);
            // }

                foreach (array_chunk($data,1000) as $chunk) {

                  //  DB::table('categories')->insert($chunk);
                  Prs::insert($chunk);
                }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
            return back()->withErrors('حدث خطأ أثناء عملية التحميل!');
        }
        return back()->withSuccess('تم تحميل البيانات بنجاح.');
    }
```

AND HERES MY AXIOS REQUEST :

```
  const importData = async fileName => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ...', 
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
        let percentCompleted = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
        console.log(progressEvent.total)

        // do whatever you like with the percentage complete
        // maybe dispatch an action that will update a progress bar or something
      },
    }

    let data = new FormData()
    data.append("file", fileName)
 
    await axios
      .post("/api/importData/", data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      }) 
      .then (  response => {

        router.push({ name: 'prs' })
        swal({
          toast: true,
          position: 'top-end',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3000,
          timerProgressBar: true,
          icon: "success",
          title: "[ PR ] has been [IMPORTED] successfully  ",
        })
      })

      .catch(function (err) {
        swal({
          toast: true,
          position: 'top-end',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3000,
          timerProgressBar: true,
          icon: "error",
          title: err,
        })
      })
 
  }
```

as I said , on ,my local machine works fine but not doing anything on live server!

Comment: have you try to debug with dd($request->all()) in first line of your function importData, top of request validation. it's just make sure that your data successfully send to your controller. if the dd show result of request data, it's probably the problem is in your validation

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's dev tools "network" tab to see if you are getting a response from the server with an error message?

Comment: haven't tried that yet, but to be in mind,  even if I pass a pdf file or any type other than xlsx it returns respones as true which seems that the data not passed to the controller at all as if it's not triggered